# NSFetchedResultsController section by number of objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` returning around 30 objects in a single section. I have no way of setting unique section names on the said objects due to the way things are setup (I have a grid view where rows and columns are given by the data source and the user can delete any cell).

Is there any way to coerce `NSFetchedResultsController` to return say 5 objects per section?

Comment: Could you explain this *I have a grid view where rows and columns are given by the data source and the user can delete any cell*? It's not clear for me?

Comment: How do you imagine it deciding which five?

Comment: @flexaddicted I think he means a table view.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse. It is a custom UIScrollView that displays cells as Grid. I configured it so that the data source can drive both the number of rows and number of columns in a cell.

Comment: I solved this by adding a transient property to the model, the NSFetchedResultsController uses this as the sectionNameKeyPath , finally as it fetches data I loop thru the result and set this property to the appropriate value (mainly bucketing n objects to a row).